# My C Drive in windows 7 is nearly full but is not real

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I installed my Windows 7 in 3-4 months ago and it ran very well until yesterday. My C drive is about 40Gb. The combined total of all the visible folders in the root directory of my C drive is 16Gb (including the Windows folder), but my system tells me that I have only 1.13Gb of free space. I haven't installed any Programs and Updates. What can I do?

Comment: Windows 7 is a pig, just the windows folder can take almost 20gb of space, 40GB of Hard dirve is just enough for windows 7 OS but not enough to have software/apps/games/etc. as Bigbio2002 suggested you should run: Treesize Free and check which folder is causing it: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/TreeSizeFree.zip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run `chkdsk /f`. If the problem still occurs, you might want to use a utility like TreeSize to see if there are any hidden files taking up space. Although it's also possible that your HDD could be dying...

Comment: I install TreeSize Program and find the big size temp. My temp was about 22 Gb. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

IT is because of your `PageFile` . page file is not visible until you disable the "Hide protected operating system files" on `folder option`.
after that you can see what is the exact cause of `Low Disk Space`.
it is good to run a `Clean Disk` but it is not a solution. in such these cases you should handle `PageFile` your self by going to 
Control Panel > System > Advance > Performance Options > Advance > here change the size of virtual memory. do not allow windows manage it.

and choosing a size for your page file that can suit your HDD capacity.

I hope this will work. let us know about the result.

Comment: It could be also hibernation file. On modern computer with 16GB for example it will be... 16GB!

Answer (score 1):

See if you have shadow copies enabled. Restore points could be eating up the HD space.

Open **My Computer** and *right-click* the **C:** drive. Select **Properties**.

Go to the **Previous Versions** tab. Do you see a lot of restore points? If so, they can be removed, or disabled altogether.

Open the **Control Panel**.
**Control Panel** > **System and Security** > **System**

Click **System Protection** in the left pane.
Highlight *Local Disk (C:)(System)* and click **Configure...**

From here you can press **Delete** to remove all the restore points and then reduce the **Max Usage** slider lower to something more reasonable.

There is also the option to **Turn off system protection** if you really low on disk space.

Comment: Sir, I created an account in this site just to up vote your answer and thank you personally. I have struggled with this issue for so many years ending up re-installing windows every time when the solution has been so simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons so try all suggestions :-) I'm sure all the space can't be missing due to temporary files but here's a program that may help a little. It deletes old, unsued and temporary files/logs. http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER

I don't think anyones mentioned this and it is simple so I may be stating the obvious. Make sure you are viewing hidden files/folders. To do this go to this open C: and go to "folder options" (you may need to press <kbd>alt</kbd> to see it) select "view" tab and select "show hidden files, folders and drives" and hit apply.

Comment: CCleaner just search in `recycle bin`, `Temporary internet files` and also in `registry` I am not sure in this case it help

Comment: @nfarshchi you're probably right but if this is a combination of problems it would help.